# Edit menu parent element

Tags: menus

I've custom menu with custom walker and I have custom 'li' elements. But how can I edit parent element?

Example menu

```
<ul id="some-weirdly-generated-id" data-i-want="some-data-here">
    ...
    <li class="already-custom"> Menu item </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

I am editing 'li' elements in "start_el(..)" fcion of my worker ...

```
public function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {
        $indent = ($depth) ? str_repeat("\t", $depth) : '';      
        $li_attributes = '';
        $class_names = ''`
        ...
        /* I AM EDITING MY LI ELEMENT HERE */
}
```

But where the hell I can edit "UL" element? Tyvm for tips!

Answer (score 0):

For the top most `ul` output by `wp_nav_menu()`, you can change the entire wrap of of the list items (`ul` or otherwise) with `items_wrap` arg.

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    ...
    'walker'  => new Your_Nav_Walker_Class(),
    'items_wrap' => '<ul class="your-class" data-u-want="some-data-you-want">%3$s</ul>',
    ...
));
```

[User example on Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#comment-204)

---

For `ul`s output from within nav walker (sub level menus, etc.), you can use something like:

```
function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent\n";
}
function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "$indent\n";
}
```

Altering $depth to target submenus at different levels.

[`Nav_Walker` boilerplate on github](https://gist.github.com/kosinix/5544535)